# RouteLink in HtmlHelper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routelink

How can I make up a RouteLink in a custom HtmlHelper? I know how to make it in a partial view but I want to build up a new link in a custom htmlhelper extension method with the use of a RouteLink. How to accomplish this?

Update: I noticed HtmlHelper.GenerateRouteLink. But what do I need to put in as parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example. Let's suppose that you want to wrap the links into a `div` tag with some given class so that your resulting html looks like this:

```
<div class="foo"><a href="/home/index">Some text</a></div>
```

You could write the following extension method:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString CustomRouteLink(
        this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
        string className, 
        string linkText, 
        object routeValues
    )
    {
        var div = new TagBuilder("div");
        div.MergeAttribute("class", className);
        div.InnerHtml = htmlHelper.RouteLink(linkText, routeValues).ToHtmlString();
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(div.ToString());
    }
}
```

which could be used like this:

```
<%= Html.CustomRouteLink("foo", "Some text", 
    new { action = "index", controller = "home" }) %>
```

and this will produce the desired markup. Any other [overloads of `RouteLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.routelink.aspx) could be used if necessary.

Comment: Thank you. I did had some problems at first due to a missing using statement so the RouteLink wasn't known and even Resharper didn't find it correctly. I used the LinkExtensions RouteLink method now.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get an instance of the UrlHelper you should be able to do whatever you want to do in your HtmlHelper method

```
UrlHelper url = new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
```

Comment: It should be new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext);

Comment: This does not seem to be going the right direction. Any other suggestion?

Comment: This did the trick for me, but as Nyla said, it's new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext)